# Moving div horizontally on click of 4 different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page on which there is div "celpage" with absolute position which contains all the content of the page, basically containing 4 different divs placed side by side.

I have four buttons in a header:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="navlist">
<li><a href="" id="Logo" class="Logo"><div id="centeredLogo"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="" id="Folio" class="Folio"><div id="centeredFolio"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="" id="Storitve" class="Storitve"><div id="centeredStor"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="" id="Kontakt" class="Kontakt"><div id="centeredKont"></div></a></li>
```

I want this div "celpage" to move 875 to the left when clicked on Folio, 2x875 when clicked on Storitve and 3x875 when clicked on Kontakt and vice versa, so when clicked on button the page would scroll to corresponding div meant to be shown for that button.

I would practically like to achieve the same effect as this http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/jquery/horizontal_scroll/, only on a whole page (except for header and footer which would remain static).

These 4 divs are made of 20 or so smaller rectangular divs with absolute positions. If I set relative position to "celpage" the sliding works, however the whole layout of the page is no longer centered. I am looking for a sliding solution for div with absolute position.

I created a jsFiddle to illustrate the page: http://jsfiddle.net/rUaYr/1/

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried something using the example you provided?

Comment: I have tried the example provided, replacing .contentbox-wrapper with .celpage and 600 with 875, however when I click on the buttons nothing happens.

Comment: Post your code here and create a jfiddle so we can see why it's not working.

Comment: Page is made of 115x125/240x125/115x250 rectangular divs with absolute position, contained inside "celpage" div and unfinished code for it is 180 lines html and +1000 lines css. I don't think I can post it here, pasting it all on jsfiddle won't even show a page made of mostly images... :S

Comment: I can upload the last version online and post a link if that helps...

Comment: Ok, now I experimented and added relative position to "celpage" class, the sliding works now but vertically everything is moved from center of the page to top with only half of it shown. How can I center the page vertically with relative position?

Comment: Without seeing any of the css, it's virtually impossible to give you an informed answer.  Are there 1000+ lines of css that deal with the positioning of these eleemnts?  Strip that code out into a boiled down jsfiddle that illustrates the problem and you'll get much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek is in the tutorial you posted. All you need to change is the container element.

Comment: I know the answer I seek is in the tutorial I posted. Obviously if it worked with my page I wouldn't be posting here...